# How transformation of co-ordinates system relates to its vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, probability-theory

Consider a positive definite matrix. Can we consider that it has a underlying co-ordiante system? If we transform that co-ordinate system how the the vectors are transformed? Is this question even valid?

Answer (score 1):

In linear algebra, a matrix $A$ is regarded as a linear map relating two vector spaces let us say $E$ and $F$. This matrix is completely determined by its action on each basis vectors of $E$. So if one wants to write $A$ as an array of numbers then one has to choose a basis of $E$.
If one changes the basis, vectors are transformed with the help of change-of-basis matrices. For more information about this see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Change_of_coordinates_of_a_vector).